# Check Vue component data after method has been triggered with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I’m trying out Jest to write unit tests for some of my components. What I’m trying to do here is to check if the output of selectedErrand is >= 0 after the toggleExtended method has been triggered.

**Error:**

```
Matcher error: received value must be a number

Received has value: undefined
```

What am I missing here?

setData to default state of selectedErrands, mock the toggleExtended method and then check to see if the selectedErrands data (state) has changed it's value according to the index of the list that's being rendered in my Vue .

I figured I could do something like this.

**Jest**

```
it(“Test”, () => {
    wrapper.setData({ selectedErrand: -1 });
    wrapper.vm.toggleExpanded();
    expect(wrapper.vm.selectedErrand).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0);
  });
```

**Vue component**

```
<template>
  <div
    v-if="!error"
    class="flex-table flex-table--white-background flex-table--green-header flex-table--with-dropdown"
    :class="{ loading: loading }"
  >
    <div class="flex-table__row flex-table--header text--level-6">
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
        {{ statusHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
        {{ idHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-7">
        {{ descriptionHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-5">
        {{ typeHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
        {{ dateOpenedHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
        {{ dateClosedHeader }}
      </div>
      <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-1" />
    </div>

    <div
      v-for="(errand, index) in sliceArray(errands)"
      :key="!errand.id ? index : errand.id"
    >
      <div
        class="flex-table__row"
        :class="{ 'flex-table__row--closed': index !== selectedErrand }"
        @click="toggleExpanded(index)"
      >
        <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
          {{ errand.status }}
        </div>
        <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
          {{ errand.id }}
        </div>
        <div
          class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-7 flex-table__cell--show-on-mobile"
          :data-header="descriptionHeader"
        >
          {{ errand.description }}
        </div>
        <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-5">
          {{ errand.type }}
        </div>
        <div
          class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3 flex-table__cell--show-on-mobile"
          :data-header="dateOpenedHeader"
        >
          {{ errand.orderDate }}
        </div>
        <div class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-3">
          {{ errand.deliveryDate }}
        </div>
        <div
          class="flex-table__cell flex-table__cell--width-1 flex-table__cell--dropdown-show-on-mobile"
        >
          <i
            class="icon-angle__small"
            :class="{ 'icon-angle__small--down': selectedErrand === index }"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <ErrandsListDetails
        v-if="selectedErrand >= 0 && selectedErrand === index"
        :errand="errand"
        v-bind="$props"
      />
    </div>

    <div
      v-if="errands.length >= numberOfErrandsLoaded"
      class="flex-table--load-more text--level-5"
    >
      <a href="#" @click="loadMore">
        {{ showMoreText }}
        <i class="icon-down" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div
      v-if="errands.length < 1 && !loading"
      class="flex-table--error text--level-5"
    >
      {{ noCasesText }}
    </div>
    <div v-if="error && !loading" class="flex-table--error text--level-5">
      {{ errorText }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";
import ErrandsListDetails from "./ErrandsListDetails.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    ErrandsListDetails: ErrandsListDetails
  },
  props: {
    componentTitle: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "";
      }
    },
    showMoreText: {
      type: String,
      default: "Visa fler ärenden"
    },
    statusHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Status";
      }
    },
    dateOpenedHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Beställt/Anmält";
      }
    },
    dateClosedHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Beräknad klar";
      }
    },
    idHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Ärendenummer";
      }
    },
    descriptionHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Beskrivning";
      }
    },
    typeHeader: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Typ";
      }
    },
    fileDetails: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Ladda ned beställningen som PDF:";
      }
    },
    commentsDetails: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Noteringar";
      }
    },
    wordList: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "";
      }
    },
    attachment: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "";
      }
    },
    noCasesText: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Det finns inget att visa";
      }
    },
    errorText: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "Något gick fel";
      }
    },
    createdOnFallback: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "-";
      }
    },
    closedOnFallback: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return "-";
      }
    },
    errands: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => {
        return [];
      }
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: () => {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedErrand: -1,
      error: undefined,
      numberOfErrandsLoaded: 10
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleExpanded: function(index) {
      this.selectedErrand = this.selectedErrand === index ? -1 : index;
    },

    loadMore: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.numberOfErrandsLoaded += 10;
    },

    sliceArray: function(array) {
      let val = _.orderBy(array, "orderDate", "desc");
      return val.slice(0, this.numberOfErrandsLoaded);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I hope this was explained correctly but feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

Thanks beforehand,
Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `toggleExpanded` expects number as param

```
toggleExpanded: function(index) {
  this.selectedErrand = this.selectedErrand === index ? -1 : index;
}
```

However, you are not passing anything. Value of `selectedErrand` is -1 initially therefore you end up with `-1 === undefined` and end up with `undefined` in `this.selectedErrand`.

You should pass the index when calling `toggleExpanded`.

```
wrapper.vm.toggleExpanded(1);
```